# Jquery ui exclude certain links from ui changes

Tags: html, jquery-ui, button, anchor

I've been jquery ui for a while and am finding it useful

Is there a way to exclude buttons made from an anchor from being changed?

for example:

any anchor with the class exclude will have a normal link

anything else without a class is a jquery ui button

the jquery code i am using is:

```
 $( 'a,input[type=submit]' ).button();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $( 'a,input[type=submit]' ).not('.exclude').button();
```

Comment: Thank you this has been very frustrating and it is good to get an response